# User email by channel ID

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to get the email of a user having their channel ID?

In this example, I am trying to get the email of the user who left a comment under a video, but there is only the channel ID.

```
"authorChannelId": {
                            "value": "UCNLNkYTttHytlMhVXP5skhA"
                       },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, unfortunately it's not possible to obtain an user's email address. That info is private data attached to any given YouTube's account.

Comment: How do people on freelancing sites claim to be able to do so as if it is the easiest thing?

Comment: @Abhishek Rai: Those that claim such things -- if their claims are indeed true -- do not use the API, for sure. They are relying (have to rely) on methods that lie outside the API (most likely are based on web scraping). There's another possibility, though kind of unlikely, that some of those sites are in possesion of business contracts with Google/YouTube that enable them access to user's private data.

Comment: The business links part makes sense..I don't see how else can they do it.

Comment: @Abhishek Rai: Web scraping is quite possible, though tricky and forbidden by Google's [DTOS specs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies) section III.E.6.